# tHashInput showing error but cant see anything in component, only can see in java code

Tags: java, talend

Good day,

In my `tHashInput`, I saw the component having the error sign, as follow:

[image]

I click on the component tab, try to figure out what is the error, however, I cant see anything inside.

But if I view it in java code, I can see where is the error, as follow:

[image]

Maybe previous developer want to put comment or print it, but make some mistake there.

May I know how can I comment this line? Java code is just for view only not editable right? Any way I can find in the Component tab for this sentence String?

I am new to Talend and first day working on Talend Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to right click on the component then click on option `Desactivate thashinput`

Other information you need to know after , the  `tHashInput` component must be intialized by a  `tHashOutput` COmponent

Comment: you are right. Need to have tHashOutput.